# Apply raster data to points from multiple years

Tags: qgis, raster, point

I am quite new to QGIS so please bear with me.

My data set is of presences data with latitude, longitude, month, and year of cetaceans. The time frame is from different months and from the year 1990 to 2018. I have multiple raster files for sea surface temperature for each month and year and I want to apply the sea surface temperature with the appropriate data point.

I have applied bathymetry data and slope to my points by using the following code in the field calculator

```
raster_value('rast', 1, make_point($x, $y))
```

Is there any way I could do change or add to this code to apply the data to the correct year and month?

or

Does any one know of a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Have you had a look at the SAGA-tool `add raster values to points`? If so, how does it not suit your needs?

Comment: I tried that and it give me and error. Plus I still need a way to only select the appropriate date. For example, I don't want to apply a raster data from 2012 to data from 2018.

Comment: which temperature files are you using?

Comment: You'll need to program a little, to iterate for each date and get the raster value, or maybe using the case when function in field calculator

Comment: I am using .nc files. I have been trying to figure out how to code for each month and year but am having no luck.